# Add uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel source to my project

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I would like to add the code from the  uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel to my project so that I can make some modifications in it. Through this emitter, the conversion to Excel works for me, but I would like to add something somewhere. Is there a way for a given library to attach its source files, modify them, and have it load my modified source files instead of the original ones when loading the source codes?

I tried adding a new plug-in from an existing spudsoft jar file and I'm having problems with the Emitter ID:

EmitterID com.asol.birt.excel.XlsxEmitter for render option is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a fork of the official BIRT sources https://github.com/eclipse-birt/birt and then modify the source files as you like.

At least that's what I did to include yaytay's latest changes, see https://github.com/triestram-partner/birt

Before I created the fork, I used to replace *.class files inside the *.jar files directly (you also need to remove the signing info then), which did work, but seemed kind of dirty to me.